# New motherboard, audio device detected, but no sound heard

Tags: windows-7, audio, motherboard

I had a PC with an old motherboard and CPU (ASUS A7V8X + Intel Core2Duo). Some days ago I decided to upgrade Motherboard, CPU and RAM.

I bought an [ASUS H61M-K](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H61MK/) and an [Intel core i3-3220](http://ark.intel.com/products/65693/Intel-Core-i3-3220-Processor-(3M-Cache-3_30-GHz)), with a 1600MHz 4GB RAM module from Corsair. My old graphics card (ATI 3870) and hard disks were compatible with the new motherboard, so I did not upgrade them.

I built my new PC, installed Windows 7 and installed everything that was on the motherboard install CD (including the Realted HD Audio driver). Everything works fine, except for the audio.

If I open the Realtek control panel and plug/unplug speakers, I can see that them are being recognized (windows also says "A new jack has been plugged in"), but I hear no sound if I try to play some music.

Why? Is there any particular setup that I should do on my motherboard to make sound work?

Comment: There are 2 locations where you can observe the sounds being "metered" in the windows mixer, and in the control pannel sounds speaker, you should be able to confirm that sound is making it through the windows system software, via this metering?  Next you try and setup as simple as possible , with stereo speakers , using very specific outputs, not just re-assiging things wherever they will go. The Green (usually front) output would be the first one to test, then the black (usually rear speakers), not changing what is normally inputs to do outputs, blue (line-in) Pink (mic-in).

Comment: The whole realtek software package installed and using the realtek audio manager software (not windows). Go to the Speakers tab,  Float your mouse over the Connections shown on the right side. This will show you what has been assigned, and also allow for re-assigning, called Re-tasking.  Again, it is far better to not use the sencing method, and instead use the manuel for setup.  Next would be to test these 2 outputs black and green, with a speaker set that just made noise (works) in something else like a MP3 player.   It will work anyway you do it, i am just suggesting to try it "normal"

Comment: Both windows mixer and Realtek software do see the speakers. Speakers do work, I was using them with the old motherboard. And I have no black port/front audio jacks. I did connect the speakers to the green port, but they aren't working

Comment: How about metering http://i.stack.imgur.com/r0fD9.png , is this sthing showing a signal when your playing a video or music or something?

Comment: @Psycogeek Maybe I wasn't clear... I **don't have** the front panel. I only have Mic/Aux/Speaker jacks on the back, directly attached to the motherboard. And yes, I can see that green bar going up and down while playing music

Comment: Oh duh, I should have seen it was a micro MB with the link you provided.  Deleting that comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Realtek HD Audio with front & back panel jack, and you got a "plugged / unplugged device message" , here`s the simple solution for this problem.

Recommended for those who have tried everything else:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsfBJdAE-Z4&list=UUzsU8j3B8ZvgJ1v-7536DhQ

Comment: Please include here the solution itself, the video is insufficient as an answer.